# Beginner Ruby question - what does the ${...} notation in String literals do?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading some Ruby code and I don't understand this snippet:

```
thing = '${other-thing}/etc/'
```

It appears to substitute a value for the `${other-thing}` and use that to build the String thing but I haven't been able to recreate this myself.

**EDIT:** Sorry to all, it turns out there was some preprocessing going on by Maven (a Java build tool).  The accepted answer shows how one could do the substitution in straight Ruby.

Comment: Where are you seeing this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> a = "Hello"  
=> "Hello"
irb(main):002:0> b = "world"
=> "world"
irb(main):003:0> puts "${a}, ${b}!"    # Doesn't work.
${a}, ${b}!
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts "#{a}, #{b}!"    # Works fine.
Hello, world!
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> puts '#{a}, #{b}!'    # Doesn't work.
#{a}, #{b}!
=> nil
```

You wanted `#{...}`, not `${...}` I believe.  Also, you don't get substitutions inside of single-quoted strings, only double-quoted (or equivalents – there's dozens of ways to delimit strings in Ruby).

Comment: It's definitely ${...}.  It is possible someone has added the behavior somewhere in the code?

Comment: May be it is stupid, but isn't it some kind of environment variable ?